# regex to ignore number followed by a word/non-numeric character

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

In Python, I am trying to anonymise or mask n number of characters (from the last). It works for the match but I want to ignore the words as well which contains numbers.

e.g

```py
string = 'SomeText +12 555 660 000 f00b4r abc123'
digits = 5
repl_char = 'X'

regex = '[0-9\s\+]+'

for match in re.finditer(regex, string):
    phone_no = match.group()
    new_ph_no = ''
    i = 0
    if phone_no in ['', ' ']:
        pass
    else:
        for phone_digit in phone_no[::-1]:
            if phone_digit == ' ' or i >= digits:
                new_ph_no += phone_digit
            else:
                new_ph_no += repl_char
                i += 1
        string = string.replace(phone_no, new_ph_no[::-1])
    print(string)
```

Current ouptput : `'SomeText +x2 555 6xx xxx fxxbxr abcxxx'`

Desired output : `'SomeText +12 555 6XX XXX f00b4r abc123'`

I tried adding `'[^?!a-zA-Z(0-9).*$]'` to the regex it gave the desired output but fails when I pass the string as `'SomeText +12 555 660 000'`

My intention is to print the phone number from any type of string and replace n digits with 'x' (or any character)

How do I print the desired output?

Comment: Why is marking starting at 2nd digit of `660` and why not 2nd digit of `555`?

Comment: @anubhava, looking at `digits = 5`, I believe last 5 digits of number part to be replaced, maybe?

Comment: Yes from the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lambda` in `re.sub` you can do:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'SomeText +12 555 660 000 f00b4r abc123'
>>> reg = r'(\b\d*(?: +\d+)*)((?: *\d){})(?! *\d)'
>>>
>>> print re.sub(reg.format('{5}'), lambda m: m.group(1) + re.sub(r'\d', 'X', m.group(2)), s)
SomeText +12 555 6XX XXX f00b4r abc123
>>>
>>> print re.sub(reg.format('{2}'), lambda m: m.group(1) + re.sub(r'\d', 'X', m.group(2)), s)
SomeText +12 555 660 0XX f00b4r abc123
```

**Details:**

- First regex `(\b\d*(?: +\d+)*)((?: *\d){5})(?! *\d)` matches last 5 digits that are preceded by 0 or space separated digits and not followed by optional spaces and a digit.
- In `re.sub` we use a lambda function
- Inside body of lambda function we replace each digit by letter `X`

Comment: but If I put '2' instead of '5', it doesn't work..
`>>> s = 'SomeText +12 555 660 000 f00b4r abc123'`

`>>> print(re.sub(r'(?: *\d){2}(?! *\d)', lambda m: re.sub(r'\d', 'X', m.group(0)), s))`

`>>> SomeText +12 555 660 0XX fXXb4r abc1XX`

Answer (score 1):

If number always start with + and you want to get the full number without it, use:

```
\+(\d+(?:\s\d+)*)\b
```

and it will return (from your example): `12 555 660 000`

See online: https://regex101.com/r/aEeIgK/2

Explanation:

- `\+` start by identifying a + before the beginning of our match. Escaping it as + is a regexp quantifier.
- `\b` end with a word boundary (so if is a mixed string starting with digits, it will not be part of the match).
- `(\d+(?:\s\d+)*)` withing the parenthesis `(...)` is what will be in match.

  - `\d+` one or more digits at the start is a mast. `\d` is digit; `+` quantifier for one or more.
  - `(?:\s\d+)*` optional (zero or more) strings that start with white space `\s` followed by digits.
  - `(?:...)` is a non-match parenthesis.
  - `*` quantifier for zero or more.
  - `\s` white space (just one).

Comment: `SomeText +12 555 660 000 00b4r abc123` If I remove 'f'

Comment: Also could you explain it, if possible.

Comment: @san1512 I've added word boundary at the regexp end, so it will work for the example in the comment. Added detailed explanation for the regexp.